# How to append logs implemented using slf4j into log file implemented using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have used log4j for logging my java application. I am using a third party library (jar) which uses slf4j for its logging. What I need to do to append the third party library (slf4j) logs into my log file and console.

### I am using below log4j maven versions in my code.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

In my java application I have used log4j for logging.

### My java code

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Abc.class);
```

I am using a third party library which uses slf4j logging.

### Thirdparty library code

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Xyz.class);
```

### This is my log4j.xml file

```
<Configuration status="INFO">

<CustomLevels> 
   <CustomLevel name="REPORT" intLevel="250" />  <!-- This is custom log level used in my code -->
</CustomLevels>

 <Appenders>

    <Console name='Console' target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p: %m%n"><Script name="LevelSelector" language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                        result=null;
                        switch (logEvent.getLevel())
                        {
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.FATAL:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ERROR:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.DEBUG:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.TRACE:
                            result=logEvent.getLevel();
                                  break;
                            default:result=null;                                            
                        }
                        result;
                        ]]></Script>

                    <PatternMatch key="FATAL" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="ERROR" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="WARN" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="INFO" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="DEBUG" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                </ScriptPatternSelector>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="TestAutomationLog" fileName="./log/TestAutomationLog.log">
         <PatternLayout>
            <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p: %m%n">
                    <Script name="LevelSelector" language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                        result=null;
                        switch (logEvent.getLevel())
                        {
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.FATAL:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ERROR:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.INFO:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.DEBUG:
                            case org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.TRACE:
                            result=logEvent.getLevel();
                                  break;
                            default:result=null;                                            
                        }
                        result;
                        ]]>
                    </Script>
                    <PatternMatch key="FATAL" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="ERROR" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="WARN" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="INFO" pattern="%d{dd-MMM HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="DEBUG" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                </ScriptPatternSelector>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>

<loggers>     
   <root level="report">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="TestAutomationLog"/>
   </root>  
   <logger name="com.myPackage" level="trace" /> 
   <logger name="com.thirdParty.package" level="trace" additivity="true" /><!-- additivity="true" to add into log file -->
</loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I want to add logs of "com.thirdParty.package" package into my log file i.e. TestAutomationLog.log.

Please suggest changes required.

**As an alternative**, if I can add this third party (slf4j) logs into another log file or view them in same console (where my application logs are shown) then also it will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may consider using the log4j-over-slf4j bridge so that your own logs also use slf4j, see here : https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: @Berger suggestion mentioned in [link] (slf4j.org/legacy.html) are not working. I tried both log4j-over-slf4j.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar files alternatively without changing my log4j.xml configuration details. Please suggest any other alternative. Mentioning the actual change will help a lot.